# Getting an error "File does not exist in artifact [SourceArtifact]" when working on codepipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I'm using S3 as source when creating the codepipline on "Add source stage".

During the "Add deploy stage" of codepiline i'm including the "Object URL" of the file as the artifactname but when i try to create the pipeline its failing with the error "File does not exist in artifact [SourceArtifact]" though the file is available in s3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudformation deployment tasks in CodePipeline expect source artifacts to be in .zip format.  The reference to the file within the artifact would be the path to the script within the zip file.

Per AWS documentation:

> When you use Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) as the source repository, CodePipeline requires you to zip your source files before uploading them to an S3 bucket. The zipped file is a CodePipeline artifact that can contain an AWS CloudFormation template, a template configuration file, or both.

Therefore, to correctly reference and process a Cloudformation script, follow the following steps:

1. Add your CloudFormation script (i.e. cf.yaml) to a .zip file (i.e. cf.zip)
2. Upload your zip file to S3
3. Set the .zip file as the path to the source S3 artifact (i.e. cf.zip)
4. Reference the source artifact in your deployment stage, but for the filename, reference the text file within the zip (i.e. cf.yaml)
5. Execute the pipeline

See [Edit the artifact and upload it to an S3 Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-basic-walkthrough.html#w2ab1c21c11b9)